# shell_exec / require_once / Nothing is working in plugin add_action

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, shell-exec

Worpress Site. I'm exporting order information from WooCommerce. I can run shell_exec from the functions.php file but whenever it's run inside of an action (add_action) it doesn't execute.  I've tried require_once as well as a number of other options.  I can make them run from command line, just not from within a plugin hook.  Thank you in advance.

Pretty much everything.  I've tested all the options within command line using stand alone php scripts and it works fine.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'live_order_info');
    function live_order_info(){
    $vars = "ANYDATA";
    $command = escapeshellcmd("./test.php ");
    $output = shell_exec($command.$vars);
    echo $output; }
```

I can verify that the code is doing something, just not causing the test.php script to execute.  All files have permissions set and work correctly if called from putty.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was the file path.  I had to use the absolute file path and it worked perfectly.

Putty was using the ~ symbol where it wasn't noticed and left out of the function.  I added it the file path and presto.